# What is the best way to store data with React Redux but by condition?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I wonder what is the best way to conditinally store data with redux. I want to be able to run a redux action but with condition.

Here is an example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addForecastToFavorites } from '../actions/sitesActions';

const AddToFavorites = ({currCityCode, onAddWeatherToFavorites }) => {

    return (
        <div className="flex-center">
            <i className="fa fa-heart"></i>
            <span className="btn btn-primary"
                onClick={() => { onAddWeatherToFavorites(currCityCode) }}>Add To Favorites</span>

        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    //console.log(state) ->
    // ['london', 'paris', 'paris'] - prevent store the same code twice...
    return {
        currCityCode: state.sitesReducer.cityCode,
        currFavorites:  state.sitesReducer.currFavorites,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({

    onAddWeatherToFavorites: (currCityCode) => { dispatch(addForecastToFavorites(currCityCode)) },

})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddToFavorites);
```

The onAddWeatherToFavorites function stores city codes in an array and later this array will be used to fetch all the city's weather forecasts by calling an api. I want to first check if a city code is already exists in the array and therefore not storing it. I have read about creating a custom middleware but i didn't find a well explained example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really consider having that code in the same place you update your state, that way you can just dispatch it, and then even if you have another place that is going to add favorites, you don't have to repeat the code:

```
switch(action.type) {
    case ADD_WEATHER_TO_FAVORITES: {
        const city = action.data;
        const index = state.cities.indexOf(city);
        if (index === -1) {
            let cities = [...state.favorites, city]
            return Object.assign({}, state, { cities });
        }

    }
}
return state;
```

Comment: Thanks - i'll check it later on and let you know

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check in the `currFavorites` array for the `currCityCode` value and only dispatch the action if false is returned. Here's a solution:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addForecastToFavorites } from '../actions/sitesActions';

 const isCityCodePresent=(currentCityCode, favCitiesArray)=> 
                           (favCitiesArray.find(code => code === currentCityCode));

const AddToFavorites = ({currCityCode, currFavorites, onAddWeatherToFavorites }) => {

    return (
        <div className="flex-center">
            <i className="fa fa-heart"></i>
            <span className="btn btn-primary"
                onClick={() => {!isCityCodePresent(currCityCode,currFavorites) && 
                      onAddWeatherToFavorites(currCityCode) }}>Add To Favorites</span>

        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    //console.log(state) ->
    // ['london', 'paris', 'paris'] - prevent store the same code twice...
    return {
        currCityCode: state.sitesReducer.cityCode,
        currFavorites:  state.sitesReducer.currFavorites,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({

    onAddWeatherToFavorites: (currCityCode) => { dispatch(addForecastToFavorites(currCityCode)) },

})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddToFavorites);
```

Comment: Thanks, but i would like to separate business login from ui-components...not sure it's a good practice to mix them...